# add_index error [Ruby on Rails]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-migrations

I am trying to create a "one-to-many relationship between owner and property" but I don't know why I am getting this error, after generating a model I tried to **add_index** before run **rake db:migrate** but something went wrong
Note: It's the first time to create a relation between two tables using ruby on rails and I searched in rubyonrails guide put I did't find an answer

My migration file:

```
class CreateProperties < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :properties do |t|
      t.string :p_street
      t.string :p_city
      t.string :postcode
      t.string :type
      t.integer :rooms
      t.integer :rent
      t.integer :owner_id

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :owner_id
  end
end
```

The error that appears:

```
==  CreateProperties: migrating ===============================================
-- create_table(:properties)
   -> 0.0712s
-- add_index(:owner_id)
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)/var/lib/gems/1.9.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:350:in `add_ind
ex'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:466:in `block in method_missing'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:438:in `block in say_with_time'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:438:in `say_with_time'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:458:in `method_missing'
/root/rails_project/dream_home/db/migrate/20130503044654_create_properties.rb:14:in `change'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:407:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:407:in `block in migrate'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:129:in `with_connection'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:389:in `migrate'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:528:in `migrate'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:720:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:775:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:775:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:775:in `ddl_transaction'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:719:in `block in migrate'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:700:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:700:in `migrate'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:570:in `up'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/migration.rb:551:in `migrate'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.2/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:193:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.2/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.2/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `block in execute'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.2/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.2/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `execute'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.2/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:184:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.2/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.2/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:170:in `invoke'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.2/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:143:in `invoke_task'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.2/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.2/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.2/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `block in top_level'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.2/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `run_with_threads'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.2/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `top_level'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.2/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:73:in `block in run'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.2/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.2/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`add_index` needs a table name

`add_index :properties, :owner_id`

Comment: In properties.rb I should add "belongs_to :owner" and in owners.rb I should add "has_many :properties",and thats all Am I right or there is a something need to be add in controllers ?

Comment: Yes, then you would be able to do something like Owner.find(params[:id]).properties to get all of their properties.

Comment: thanks :) I will add the relation and then try something to do :D

Answer (score 2):

You have to mention table name in the arguments.
Try `add_index (:properties,:owner_id)`

Comment: I know but I am a new comer here and I don't have enough reputation :(

Comment: Its ok. Anyways I love to help.